# Maximum value and index by a dimension in R array?

Tags: r, arrays

I have a 3-dimensional array in R. For each row of each 2-dimensional slice, I would like to find the maximum value and its index of the maximum. What is the fastest way to do this?

I have used `rowMaxs()` for each slice to find the row-wise maximum values, but this doesn't give the index, which I need to get separately with `max.col()`. This doesn't seem that efficient, as I would still need to loop over the slices, which is probably slow-ish compared to, e.g., C++.

I have seen some suggest **Rcpp**, but I haven't coded C++ in 20 years, so I was wondering if there is nowadays a package that does exactly the operation that I've described above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the absolute fastest way, but `which.max` will give you the index of the max, and then you can do something like `x[which.max(x)]` to get the value at that index

Comment: This isn'tr really an appropriate question given the style and constraints of the site.

Comment: what about `apply(your_matrix, 3, max)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, then you could use an `apply` to generate the appropriate index values and then use those to pluck out the appropriate value from the array:

```r
set.seed(207)
x <- array(sample(1:24, 24, replace=FALSE), dim=c(2,3,4))

colinds <- apply(x, c(1,3), function(x)which(x==max(x), arr.ind=TRUE))
inds <- cbind(rep(1:nrow(colinds),  ncol(colinds)), c(colinds), rep(1:ncol(colinds), each=nrow(colinds)))
out <- cbind(inds, x[inds])
colnames(out) <- c("row", "col", "face", "max")
out
#>      row col face max
#> [1,]   1   2    1  21
#> [2,]   2   2    1  24
#> [3,]   1   3    2  18
#> [4,]   2   1    2  11
#> [5,]   1   2    3  23
#> [6,]   2   1    3  19
#> [7,]   1   1    4  17
#> [8,]   2   2    4  15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How fast do you expect this to be, e.g., compared to a Rcpp implementation (which I have no idea how to do)?

Comment: Same speed as the 'running along the index' is _of course_ done in compiled code by R.